# Correct way of casting types of a plist dictionary

Tags: swift, dictionary, types, nested, plist

I am loading a dictionary of dictionaries from a plist file like so:

```
var dict:NSDictionary?
if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("ISA", ofType: "plist"){
    dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
}else{
    println("Could not load ISA file")
}
```

Given that I know the form of the dictionary, at which point should I cast its type? For example should i do:

```
return dict as [String : [String : Int]]
```

Or would it be better to return an NSDictionary and then cast the types as I use them:

```
dict.allKeys as [String]
```

EDIT:

If I do it the first way I run into trouble later when I try to access the keys:

```
var keys = d.keys
var length0 = keys[0].utf16Count
```

Produces the error:

```
LazyBidirectionalCollection<MapCollectionView<Dictionary<String,[String,Int]>,String>> is not convertible to [String]
```

Many thanks, Ben

Comment: Try and see what happens, no reason to post a question if you havent even tried...

Comment: I have tried, both work but i'm asking which is preferable

Comment: Well of course the first one, its better to cast it all in the beginning.

Comment: I have added some more information about an issue i run into when attempting the first way

Comment: Thats because keys already is of type [String], you cannot cast something into what it already is

Comment: var keys:[String] = d.keys also produces that error

Comment: Dont cast it at all, it will be the right type automatically. let keys = d.keys

Comment: But then it doesn't treat it as an array of strings and i cant call any string methods on its elements?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70957/discussion-between-benjacob-and-arbitur).

Comment: Array<Dictionary>.keys is of type [String] in your case so you dont have to do anything to it because of generics.

Comment: Example: let str = d.keys.first! <- str will be of type String

Comment: Thanks for your help but it isn't working it still produces errors

Comment: Update you code in your question how it is now please

Comment: You're accessing the array incorrectly. You access an element like this arr[n] and not arr(n) its just a syntax error